# Autocomplete search working in mozilla but not in chrome and other browsers

Tags: google-chrome

In site,  "**Autocomplete Search suggestion results**". were displaying in [all pages](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/).

but now "Autocomplete Search suggestion results" are not displaying only in [home page](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/) in **chrome** & other browsers, but working in **mozilla firefox**....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var ajaxUrl='<?php echo Mage::helper('searchsuggest')->getAjaxurl(); ?>';
        var queryDelay = 0.5;
        var progressImage ='<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/ajax-loader.gif');?>';
        var minCharacters = '<?php echo Mage::helper('searchsuggest')->getMinChar(); ?>';

        document.observe('dom:loaded',function(){
            //require(["autocomplete"], function(){
                $$('.form-search')[0].insert({
                    after:'<div id="search-autocomplete"><div id="searchr-result-containter"><div id="autocomplete-content"><div id="search-result"></div></div></div></div>'
                });
                $('searchr-result-containter').hide();
                var acLayout = new Autocomplete();
                acLayout.initAutocomplete(ajaxUrl, 'search-result');
            //});
        })
    //]]>
</script>
```

demo : if you open [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/) , you can see 3 small icons at top right, if you click on 1st icon , search box will appear , than you can type "iphone" & wait for some 1 min....

**Edit**

The reason for issue is Banner slider which is present in top, once i removed that, now "Autocomplete search" is working in All browsers

Comment: what's the double $ for in `$$('.form-search')[0].insert(`

Comment: @A.Lau we are using plugin, also i am new to js , sorry i have no idea about that.....

Comment: Try removing one of the $ and see what happens. I think this is out of my league for this one.

Comment: @A.Lau i tried , after that `autocomplete search` didt worked in mozilla browser also.....

Comment: its because of  `banner slider` present on top, once i removed that banner slider, its working in other browsers, but i need that banner slider.... you can check [here](http://sbdev3.kidsdial.com:81/)

Comment: Is the data displaying and going below banner slider ?

Comment: @Shahil yes `autocomplete search suggestion results` are displaying in `mozilaa firefox` , but not displaying in any other browser [here](http://stylebaby.com/)

Comment: You have solved may be. I have checked, no issues appeared.

Comment: @AHJeebon no its working only when i removed the `banner slider` as in [link1](http://sbdev3.kidsdial.com:81/) , but when i keep the banner slider , issue is still there in chrome and other browsers as in [link2](http://stylebaby.com/)

Comment: @AHJeebon Thanks for your preciuos time, i got solution.....

Comment: @Shahil Thanks for your preciuos time, i got solution.....

Comment: @AHJeebon Thanks for your preciuos time, i got solution.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:**
You have included your search-form inside `#header-search` area and you have added in the css 
`#header-search {height:50px;}` that is wrong.

**Solution:**
Simply add this style inside your css file (if not work then add `!important`):

```
#header-search {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 50px;
}
```

> Note: Every browser use their user-agent style sheet to fix some issues.